# Using XQuery implementation of WebLogic

Tags: weblogic, xquery, weblogic-10.x

I planning to using XQuery in J2EE web application running on WebLogic 11g. I know WebLogic has XQuery implementation but couldn't find any link on how to use them. I am looking for sample & package/class I need to start with.

Answer (score 0):

BEA Weblogic - designed the framework provided implementation for XmlBeans. later this project got migrated to apache foundation. 
Xmlbeans has an simple XQuery engine build with. you can get more pointers to know the details. 
if not you can use any of the open-source xquery engines inside weblogic.

Comment: Thanks for the update. I checked the XMLBean but it requires saxon jar. I just want to avoid importing 3rd party jar's.

Comment: XmlBeans XmlCursor or selectPath API works very will with a simple XPath expressions which is pretty much good for a schema to Object mapped Xml Data.

Comment: if you want some full-fledged XQuery engine then you may have to look into SAXON or MXQuery XQuery Engine. its a 3rd party application